Git for Windows in powershell - rebase fails as folders cannot be deleted
Today an issue started to appear on my Windows PC, and i can't find a solution to it.
Prior today, it all worked well, and out of the sudden (means, I didn't do any major updates or something with the repo) I cannot do interactive rebase anymore.
The rebase itself is working well, however when it comes to "cleaning up" it seems to delete the files in the rebase-merge folder. But when it comes to deleting the folder, it throws the error below.
After trying to figure out, what's the issue, I tried "git gc --aggressive" and same result. The objects in the folders seem go get deleted, but for any folders it throws the same error.
git version 2.47.1.windows.1
PSVersion                      7.4.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631

but

Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again?
(y/n)

What I have tried:

instead of by Powershell do the same with WSL-Ubuntu --- works without issue
Manually deleting the folders --- works without issue
Run Powershell as admin --- issue happens
mark git.exe specifially to run with admin rights --- issue happens
Check all user right for folders and sub-folder - permission (specially for Admin) is there

Update:
I seems there is a permission issue:
  Everyone:(I)(CI)(DENY)(DC)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
  PC\USER:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

But here comes the problem. I enabled auditing, and it seems, that the "Everyone" (Deny) permission is added by OneDrive.exe...

Do you use anything that might block the folder, like prompt that checks branch status?

Unfortunatly not... When I delte manually (either by Explorer, nor Powershell, there is no issue)
